# Looping back to a menu

Tags: c, do-while

I am trying to create a menu function that loops back to spot 0 a.k.a back to the menu above the start of the do while loop when spots 1 and 2 's if statement have been met. Can anyone provide some help on that?

```
#include <stdio.h>          //library including standard input and output functions
#include <stdlib.h>         //library including exit and system functions used below
#include <string.h>         //library including string functions used


struct packet{
    int source;
    int destination;
    int type;
    int port;
    char data[50];
    char * filename;
};

int main ()
{
    struct packet s[50]; //Array for structure input
    char choice;
    int NetworkPacket = 0, ii = 0;
    int recordCount = 0;
///// SPOT 0//////
    do{

        system("cls");
        puts("Please enter an option:\n");
        puts("'A' Add a packet:\n");
        puts("'D' to Display the Packet List:\n");
        puts("'S' to Save the Packets to a file:\n");
        puts("'C' to Clear the list of current saved packets:\n");
        puts(" or X to exit the program...\n");

        //wait for user input
        scanf("%c", &choice);   //take the first char of user input and assing the value to
                                //the variable choice using the address of (&) the variable
        if(choice == '\n')      //check to see that the character is not \n left over from the
            scanf("%c", &choice);   //previous choice made, if it is then we need to scan the input again

        switch (choice)
        {
            case 'A': 
                system("cls"); //clear the screen
////SPOT 1//////
                if(NetworkPacket==50){
                    printf("No more network packets can be added");
                    getch();
                }
                else{}

 ////SPOT 1//////
                printf("\n****Adding a packet*****\n");
                printf("Where is the packet from?\n");
                scanf("%i", &s[NetworkPacket].source);
                printf("Where is the packet going?\n");
                scanf("%i", &s[NetworkPacket].destination);
                printf("What type is the packet?\n");
                scanf("%i", &s[NetworkPacket].type);
                printf("What is the packet's port?\n");
                scanf("%i", &s[NetworkPacket].port);
                printf("Enter up to 50 characters of data.\n");
                scanf("%s", s[NetworkPacket].data);
                NetworkPacket++;
                break;

            case 'D': 
                system("cls"); //clear the screen
                printf("\nDisplaying Infomation\n");
 ////SPOT 2//////
                if(NetworkPacket==0){
                    printf("no records yet, Please press any key to revert back to the main menu\n");
                    getch();
                }
                else{}
 ////SPOT 2//////
                for(ii = 0; ii < NetworkPacket; ii++) {    // adds a 1 onto the NetworkPacket counter keeping a tally on the number of records stored.
                    printf("\nSource: %d", s[ii].source);
                    printf("\nDestination: %d", s[ii].destination );
                    printf("\nType : %d", s[ii].type);
                    printf("\nPort : %dgetch();", s[ii].port);
                    printf("\nData: %s\n---\n", s[ii].data);
                } break;

            case 3: 
                break;

            system("cls");
            break;

            case 4: break;
            case 5: break;

            default:
                system("cls");
                printf("%c is not an option\n Try again...\n", choice);
        }
    }while(choice!='X' && (NetworkPacket >= 50? (printf("No more network packets can be added" ), 0) : 1));
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Why do you have instruction that are not in a case? Just a `break` copy pasted? (case 3)

Answer (score 0):

Use the continue directive like so:

```
if (something_cool_happened)
    continue;
```

This will cause the do-while loop to end the current iteration and go back to the beginning of the loop.  This also works for while loops and for loops

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if I have understood your question correctly. But to execute the next iteration of the loop, you can use continue statement.

Comment: I want the case switch menu to work as normal unless the if statement condition is met, then it would loop back to the menu, but at the moment it loops back to the menu regardless if the if statement condition is met or not

Comment: So you mean to say that the loop should start executing again if the 'if statement' condition is satisfied?  In that case have a boolean variable flag set to one when the condition is satisfied and break out of the switch. Outside the switch, check for the value of the flag and do the necessary operations.

Answer (score 0):

@Dinesh's answer should solve your issue. However, as an add on, don't you want to allow the user to display or save to files when NetworkPacket>=50? You are terminating in the while if this happens. You should check for this condition only when user tries to add another NetworkPacket right?.

Forgive me if I have misunderstood the question.